# iOS App development in Swift for iPAD

Tags: ios, ipad

I have 4 container views inside my main view controller. The problem I am facing is that, when simulating for different applications (iPAD Retina and iPAD Pro), the container size remains fixed and hence in some devices, some containers are lost and some in a distorted shape. SO the question is how can I auto adjust the size of the container according to the screen size of the device?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at auto-layout and constraints (see links below). Constraints will allow you to set rules, that your views will follow (e.g. width of view1 must be equal to width of view2, or view1 has to be left aligned with view2). You can either set it programmatically or through IB:

[Auto layout Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/%20Autolayout%20Apple%20Doc)

[Autolayout Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

EDIT: That is way better than manually set the size with frame. Indeed, if you do so, you will have to reset frame when your superview will change. With auto layout (or even with autoresizing masks) it will be done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode there is a size inspector. If you go to your storyboard then select your desired ViewController, you will see a size inspector bottom of Xcode.

If you click there, it will show you a combination of screen sizes. After selecting a combination, it will show you which type of device it will support.

Select your desired layout & put your containers on it. Do not use fixed width of the container. Use auto layout to set these containers.